# Can you rename "table of contents" in the Sphinx sidebar?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sidebar

More generally how do you rename Sphinx default elements (e.g. `Quick Search` to `Search`)? Can you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you could change "Quick search" to something else by overriding a template:

1. Create a folder called `templates` in the Sphinx project directory.
2. Copy `<Sphinx install dir>/themes/basic/searchbox.html` to `templates`.
3. In conf.py, add

   ```
   templates_path = ["templates"]
   ```
4. Rename 'Quick search' to whatever you want in the copy of `searchbox.html`.

But I would not do it this way.

A more flexible approach is to create a gettext MO file and set up the configuration as described in [the documentation for **locale_dirs**](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/config.html#confval-locale_dirs). Like this:

1. The template file `<Sphinx install dir>/locale/sphinx.pot` contains all the strings that can be translated. Copy that file to a local `sphinx.po` file.
2. Add your changes to `sphinx.po`.
3. Use **msgfmt.py** to compile `sphinx.po` into `sphinx.mo`.
4. Put `sphinx.mo` in the proper directory (`<your_locale_dir>/en/LC_MESSAGES` for English).

See also http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#internationalizing-your-programs-and-modules.

Comment: The instructions for the "propper" way are not (or no longer) quite precise. It's not necessary to copy the translations from the install's default .po file. You also don't need to use **msgfmt.py** for compilation, as long as [gettext_auto_build](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-gettext_auto_build) is set.

Answer (score 1):

According to Sphinx config [documentation](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/config.html), you should be able to amend the html templates or perhaps point Sphinx to new templates to achieve what you trying to do by working on the templates' html.

Current templates have search title provided in the context, I am not sure though what populates context value for _('search'). I wander if you could try customizing it by amending the locale file in /sphinx/sphinx/locale/sphinx.pot:

```
#: sphinx/themes/agogo/layout.html:49 sphinx/themes/basic/layout.html:137
#: sphinx/themes/basic/search.html:11 sphinx/themes/basic/search.html:20
msgid "Search"
msgstr ""
```

and say `msgstr "My alternative search"` instead of `msgstr ""`.

Comment: The pot file is a gettext catalog template - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext